# Hypotheses for floating quantifier's positions in generative grammar

Tags: syntax, syntax-trees, generative-grammar, transformations, movement

Regarding the floating quantifiers' theory on external argument's movement.

These data raises two different problems:

```
a) The dogs ALL should have been petted.

b) *The dogs should have been ALL petted.
```

**a)** There seems to be no room for a possible landing site of the NP subject *the dogs* between [Spec, AgrP] and the head [Agr0] - or [Spec, IP] and [I0] if we don't take into account Split-IP hypothesis.

Where does *all* get stranded in a) in the syntax tree?

**b)** Why *all* cannot be stranded there? Theoretically, that position could be either be [Spec,VP] of the verb *pet* or [Spec,IP] of the participle inflection of *(pet)-ted*.

How does the theory account for the ungrammaticality of b)?

Comment: Ask the authors, not us.

Comment: What are talking about?

Comment: Precisely my point.

Comment: "Regarding the floating quantifiers' theory on external argument's movement."  Please explain this.

Comment: The so called VP-internal subject hypothesis. It is well known in generative grammar since Sportiche (late '80s).

Comment: @AntonMariaPrati Who claims that your example (b) is ungrammatical? I can construct parallel cases which sound fine to me, e.g. "The pastries should've been all sold by now". It's somewhat marked compared to the alternative, but i'm not sure i would say it was ungrammatical.

Comment: @AntonMariaPrati Boskovic (2001, p4, example 5a) for example gives a construction parallel to your (b) as being grammatical.

Comment: So, perhaps, the floated Q position is not predicted by Spec AgrP. Don't believe everything you read in a syntax book.